# AJAX not returning the values form JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, netbeans, jdbc

i am trying to retrieve values from jsp using ajax as explained here [here](http://www.programdiary.in/2013/01/jspwithajax.html) . but its not returning the values from the DB.Please help with this

**home page**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jsp Page</title>
        <script>
            function showuser(str)
            {
                var xreq;
                if (str == "")
                {
                    document.getElementById("showtext").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    xreq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xreq.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if ((xreq.readyState == 4) && (xreq.status == 200))
                    {
                        document.getElementById("showtext").innerHTML
                                = xreq.responseText;

                    }
                }
                xreq.open("get", "getuser.jsp?q=" + str, "true");
                xreq.send();

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="user" onchange="showuser(this.value)" >
                <option value="">Select Student name....</option>
                <option value="abhi">abhi</option>
                <option value="alex">alex</option>
                <option value="adam">adam</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <div id="showtext">The response will come here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**DB connection establishment page**

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>jsp Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%! Connection con;%>
        <%! Statement s;%>
        <%! ResultSet rs;%>

        <% String name = request.getParameter("st");

            try {

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("URL");
                s = con.createStatement();
                rs = s.executeQuery("select * from studentinfo where name='" + name + "'");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        %>

        <div id="dtl_table"><table border='3' cellpadding='5'
                                   cellspacing='2' width="400px">
                <tr bgcolor="66FF00">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Branch</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Email id</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <% while (rs.next()) {
                    %>
                    <td><%= rs.getString("NAME")%></td>
                    <td><%= rs.getString("BRANCH")%></td>
                    <td><%= rs.getString("YEAR")%></td>
                    <td><%= rs.getString("EMAIL")%></td>
                    <% }%>
                </tr>
            </table></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE studentinfo(
   name VARCHAR2(30),
   branch VARCHAR2(20),
   year VARCHAR2(20),
   email VARCHAR2(80) 
);
```

Comment: _"its not returning the values from the DB"_ - What actually does happen? Do you get any errors in the browser's console or server-side? Also, why is this tagged 'jquery' when you seem to be using plain JavaScript with no jQuery? And please, _indent your code_ so that it is readable.

Comment: @nnnnn its not showing error it doesnt print any values from DB printing the table headers alone.. I am using netbeans , should i add any jquery files to execute this??

Comment: @sankrish while using ajax request always use firebug in the browser so that u can see what exactly happen when u send the request and what u are getting

Comment: @deepak thanks for your comment , But where should i check in firebug

Comment: _"should i add any jquery files to execute this?"_ - No, the code you've shown doesn't use any jQuery functions.

Comment: @sankrish in console and net pannels .Enable all panels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameter `st` in the request Object

```
String name=request.getParameter("st");
```

The parameter you are passing is `q`

```
xreq.open("get","getuser.jsp?q="+str,"true");
```

Comment: How could i replace 2nd JSP page with servlet.. Is that possible,Because i want to avoid the usage of scriplets

Comment: Can u please edit ur answer with a servlet , instead of using a JSP

Comment: try posting a new Question